# How to configure dagger + gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

I have a project and migrating to gradle dependency, but I find myself with an issue trying to setup dagger with gradle, the first time I compile it work perfectly (or if I clean) but if I try it twice then it gives me error like:

Error:(13, 14) error: duplicate class: com.myapp.android.application.InjectingApplication$InjectingApplicationModule$$ModuleAdapter

I try using android-apt plugin and configured as in the documentation but I still get the same error (https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/overview)

I also try using provided dependency instead like in this tutorial (https://github.com/frankdu/android-gradle-dagger-tutorial) of compile but no luck so far.

Do you have any ideas how to configure  dagger and gradle?

**EDIT**

My build.gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        packageName "com.myapp.android"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':volley')
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.0'
}
```

And my top level build.gradle look like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

EDIT#2:

I tried with provided again as @Marco suggested no luck, I don't know if there is a library or a version of gradle that could be causing this problem, I'm currently using 1.10. On the bright side I did find a way to make it work, but I would love to do it by just adding the provided statement. The way I did it is the old way:

Define apt configuration

```
configurations {
     apt
}
```

add Dagger compiler lib

```
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
```

And implement the this hook to applicationVariant which as far as I know android-apt does something similar. Does this make sense? why?

```
def getSourceSetName(variant) {
    return new File(variant.dirName).getName();
}

android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
    def aptOutputDir = project.file("build/source/apt")
    def aptOutput = new File(aptOutputDir, variant.dirName)


    android.sourceSets[getSourceSetName(variant)].java.srcDirs+= aptOutput.getPath()

    variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
            '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
            '-s', aptOutput
    ]

    variant.javaCompile.source = variant.javaCompile.source.filter { p ->
        return !p.getPath().startsWith(aptOutputDir.getPath())
    }

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle to verify how `android-apt` and your dependencies are setup?

Comment: Actually for Dagger, you don't really need android-apt anymore. Can you try to set `dagger-compiler` in `provided` in stead of `compile`. Also, the latest version of dagger is 1.2.1, maybe it's a dagger bug that is fixed now.

Comment: I tried to set it up with provided but with no luck like this, https://github.com/frankdu/android-gradle-dagger-tutorial do you recomend using provided now ?

Comment: I recommend provided for processors that generate code that you don't have to reference in your own code. `android-apt` for the cases that you do need to reference generated code, for example when working with Android annotations or `android-autovalue`

Comment: For solution on "plain java" - not android please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41815406/1010868

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am using dagger in this sample [Volley Examples](https://github.com/marcoRS/volley-examples). I'm not experiencing any problems with dagger and I'm including the compiler using:

```
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
```

Comment: Indeed, this was the right thing to do. While Hugo Visser's apt plugin worked for me for compile-time generating main sources, it failed to generate test sources and I got `Module adapter for class MyModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.` This blog post gives some more insight: http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

Comment: BTW mistery solved when I migrate the project from eclipse to gradle some of the generated class became part of the real package I found out later when inspecting each package

Answer (score 1):

It is work for me.

**Step 1:**
Add this code to you `build.gradle`

```
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

**Step 2:**
Add source code folder `app/gen` to you project. So you can add this code to you `app/build.gradle` (`src/main/java` is you project core code folder)

```
sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'gen']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Gradle plugin to (root/gradle)
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

app/gradle

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
```